# Having troubles changing 'profit' to a $ type in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking to output 'profit' as '$999.99' format but I run into errors about not having 'FROM'. Can anyone help?

```
SELECT BOOKS.TITLE as "BOOK TITLE", ((QUANTITY*PAIDEACH)-BOOKS.COST) as profit
FROM ORDERITEMS, BOOKS
WHERE ORDERITEMS.ORDER#='1002' AND BOOKS.ISBN = ORDERITEMS.ISBN;
```

Comment: Your query could be improved, but it does seem syntactically correct.

Comment: The current format of profit is '99.9', I'm looking to add a statement that converts it to '$999.99' format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT b.TITLE as "BOOK TITLE",
       TO_CHAR(((QUANTITY*PAIDEACH)-b.COST), '$#,###') as profit
FROM ORDERITEMS oi JOIN
     BOOKS b
     ON b.ISBN = oi.ISBN
WHERE oi.ORDER#='1002' ;
```